# Use mySQL to order US States alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, alphabetical

Relatively new to mySQL so this is probably an easy one:

I have a table named `Zip` with three columns:

```
Zip varchar(255)
City varchar(255)
State enum('AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA',etc.,etc., 'WY'
```

When I run the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT State FROM Zip ORDER BY State ASC;
```

I get this result:

```
+-------+
| State |
+-------+
|       |
| AL    |
| AK    |
| AZ    |
| AR    |
etc.
```

So it's sorting the list alphabetically by the first letter just fine, but it's NOT sorting alphabetically by the second.

I've searched everywhere (w3schools, dev.mysql.com, stackoverflow, Google) and I couldn't find anything about ORDER BY "the second letter/character" (or, at least, I don't think I found anything; maybe I just didn't understand).

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. Good to know the limitations of the "enum" type. As far as the Zip column being too big: I know. I wasn't the one that actually created the database. It's a group project for a class and I'm just letting this go. Don't want to argue with group members, just finish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting the enum to a character type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT State
FROM Zip
ORDER BY CAST(State AS CHAR)
```

Comment: Awesome! This works! And I don't have to back into the database to edit the data types.

Answer (score 3):

`STATE` is an enum, and therefore gets sorted by the order it's placed into the definition of that enum. (Note that you have `AZ`, `AR` in your definition, and that's how they're being ordered).

Change `STATE` to be `CHAR(2)` (since no US state abbreviations are longer than 2 letters), and your `ORDER BY` should work fine.

(Also, `ZIP` can be reduced considerably, as the max us ZIP Code is 10 characters - 5 for the ZIP, a hyphen (dash), and a +4 extension.)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't sort your enum correctly. If you would just be using standard CHAR values and no enum it would work. However you set the enum with a fixed order so it will sort like your enum was set up.

Order your enum:

```
State enum('AK','AL','AR','AZ','CA',etc.,etc., 'WY'
```